# ESP8266 GET OR POST Request Timeout Error

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

**i am using ESP8266 module serially with PC and i also tried it using uno
I am stuck at the following point
I am able to made connection to server but when i will send the following command**

POST /test.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.36\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 5\r\n\r\nb1=ON\r\n\r\n

**every time i get the following server timeout error after 3 sec**

+IPD,4,500:HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 14:10:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Content-Length: 305
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

408 Request Timeout

## Request Timeout

Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.

---

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

4,CLOSED

**And i am getting same issue whether i will use local server or online server**

Comment: If you post the same string to your server(s) from your PC, bypassing the ESP8266, do you get the same error?

Comment: no through PC i m getting the repsonse from server

Comment: Try adding `Connection: close\r\n` to the header. Also remove the `\r\n\r\n` at the end. Lastly, are you using the correct length in `AT+CIPSEND=...`?

Comment: Try turning off your firewall.

Comment: yes i am sending the correct length